# c# Console Containing -Commands

Tags: c#, browser

In my project, I want to have the user's input for the type of browser and the thing they are searching for.

Example:
UserInput = browserChrome -Google --Random StackOverFlow

- "browserChrome" would be the type of browser
- "-Google" would be the search engine
- "--Random StackOverFlow" would be the thing to search up Google
  Chrome, Google search engine, in the program, this would be based on what the user would type

Is there a way to code this? 
If there is how? I am a beginner in c#

Comment: Yes you can code this by writing code. Did you do that? Do you know about `args` named parameter of main method in Console application?

Comment: The answer to your question is _yes_.   However checkout [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you started

```
using System;

public class CommandLine
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
       {
           if( args[i] == "-Google" )
           {
               // do something
           }
       }
   }
}
```

### More resources

- [Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments)

Comment: Can you expalin this, I do not understand this. I am a beginner in c#

Comment: @transformerio I think you need to download some example projects, this example is about as simple as it comes Zane would take too lone to explain each element on SO. I wish you thr best of luck